# Commutation relation under an arbitrary Lie algebra representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

This is an exercise in [Woit's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319646109), B9, Problem 2:

> For the case of the Euclidean group $E(2)$, show that in any representation $\pi'$ of its Lie algebra, there is a Casimir operator
> $$
> |\vec{P}|^2 = \pi'(p_1)\pi'(p_1) +\pi'(p_2)\pi'(p_2)
> $$ that commutes with all the Lie algebra operators $\pi'(p_1), \pi'(p_2), \pi'(l)$.

I have a couple of doubts regarding this computation. Suppose we want to prove that it commutes with $\pi'(p_1)$. One has to compute
$$
[\pi'(p_1)\pi'(p_1) +\pi'(p_2)\pi'(p_2),\pi'(p_1)] = 0,
$$

but since $\pi'(\cdot)$ is arbitrary, I would like to "use" the definition of the Lie algebra representation

> A Lie algebra representation $(\phi,V)$ of a Lie algebra $\mathbb{g}$ on an $n$-dimensional complex vector space $V$ is given by a real-linear map $$\phi: X\in \mathbb{g}\rightarrow  \phi(X) \in \mathbb{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$$ satisfying $$\phi([X,Y]) = [\phi(X),\phi(Y)].$$

Of course this definition is for finite vector spaces (it is the one in my book), but still I can use it in my case (e.g. the Schrödinger representation is still unitary and fulfills the commutator relation above), right?

If this holds then
$$
\pi'([p_1^2+p_2^2,p_1]),
$$
where the Lie bracket is now the Poisson bracket and thus $\pi'(0)$.

Is the process above valid? Is it $\pi'(0)=0$?

Comment: I suspect the average reader will not understand your question, because there is precious little background and references  on the *π'* "representation", nor what PBs have to do with anything here.

Comment: I rewrote the question, adding more details.

Comment: You need to be careful about one thing here. The way the Casimir element was defined using a representation makes sense ($\pi(p_1)^2+\pi(p_2)^2$), as the representations live in the space of linear operators on a vector space where such products exist. However, in your last expression you write things like $p_1^2$ which does not make sense in a Lie algebra as the only product available is the commutator. There are two ways to make sense of the above
1) Define the concept of a "Universal Enveloping Algebra". Which I guess the book has not done yet.

Comment: 2) Use a simple identity, to relate the commutator you want to the Lie algebra commutator. For any associative algebra, the commutator satisfies (easy to show):

$$[AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B$$
Try using this on $[\pi(p_1)^2+\pi(p_2)^2,\pi(\cdot)]$ and then use the fact that $\pi$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the comment about Poisson Brackets. I don't know the book and not sure if there is some special context here.

Comment: @Heidar "things like $p^2$ which does not make sense in a Lie algebra as the only product available is the commutator": Yes, it is an abuse of notation but I think it is the physicists' fault, which is tradition in the field. The point with the notation is that the argument in $\pi'(\cdot)$ is also a Lie algebra, but in the space of functions defined over phase space. In this case, $[f,g]$ is identified with the Poisson bracket $\lbrace f,g\rbrace = \frac{\partial f}{\partial q}\frac{\partial g}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\frac{\partial g}{\partial q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the process above valid? Is it $\pi'(0)=0$?

Yes, it is. The phase-space origin in your  ill-met infinite-dimensional representations maps to the trivial zero operator in Hilbert space, just like the zero matrix for the  3×3 matrices provided.

Specifically, you have the E(2) brackets,
$$
[\pi'(p_1),\pi'(p_2)]=0, \qquad [\pi'(l),\pi'(p_1)]=\pi'(p_2), \qquad 
 [\pi'(l),\pi'(p_2)]=-\pi'(p_1),
$$
where your Casimir works; but it is not in the Lie algebra.

In point of fact, your target bracket can also be computed by inspection as a plain commutator of the Schroedinger realization,
$$
\pi'(l)= -q_1\partial/\partial q_2 + q_2\partial/\partial q_1     ,\qquad   \pi'(p_1)=-\partial/\partial q_1, \qquad  \pi'(p_2)=-\partial/\partial q_2, \\
\pi^{'~ 2}(p_1)+ \pi^ {'~ 2}(p_2)= \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial q_1^2}+  \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial q_2^2}~~.
$$
Note the last line is not in the Lie algebra, but it is still "represented" faithfully by this "crypto-quantization" realization.

Comment: Q. The Schrödinger representation is "the only one that exists" on a Hilbert space for finite spatial dimensions due to the Stone-von Neumann theorem. I cannot think on another representation that might be useful from the Physics point of view. Do you know if exists another one, so that the "general representation" $\pi'$ is justified to use?

Comment: Not sure how the two relate.  The  Schrödinger rep/realization is unique, up to trivial redefinitions. The quantization map ', like all such maps, is incomplete/pathological, as per the Groenewold theorem you already illustrated: you cannot evade quantum anomalies...